# Removing default onclick or onItemClick color animation

Tags: asp.net, onclick, buttonclick, graphical-logo

When I click on some button or I click on the a element in grid or list view, a default orange color appears. I don't want that color to come when I click on it. Please tell me how can I do this.
And also is it possible to change the orange color by some other custom color when i click on button or items in grid or list view.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of how to set this here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1c9e319c-79aa-4608-a302-0a6c9d93d504